# Objective-C++ C++ object destructor

Tags: c++, objective-c, objective-c++

I have an Objective-C class which one of it's variables is an C++ object (most of my code is C++, but I need some ObjC classes to integrate with iOS libraries). Does Objective-C++ guarantees that the C++ object will be correctly destroyed when the Objective-C object is destroyed?

Some example code:

```
class MyCppClass {
    // ...
};

@interface MyObjCClass : NSObject {
    MyCppClass myCppObject; // is it ok to do it?
}

// ...

@end
```

Comment: As long as you don't include that header in a normal `.m` file, you should be fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  After the `-dealloc` method is called, a hidden `.cxx_destruct` method is called.  This method calls all the destructors of all instance variables that have a destructor.